# MongoDB Aggregate with match between dates (100M+ documents)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a system that records all the user actions like a log system. I want to perform an aggregate that groups all the users by its id and creates a list with its actions.

With a database of **110M of documents** with the following structure that register user actions :

```
user_action
{
    id_user: ObjectId(...),
    created_at: Date(...),
    action: {object},
}
```

*(Both id_user and created_at has indexes.)*

The following aggregate tries to group all the users actions by a given day :

```
db.user_action.aggregate([
{ '$match': {'created_at': { $gte:ISODate("2016-06-05"), $lt:ISODate("2016-06-06")}}},
{ '$group': {
    '_id' :{'id_user': '$id_user'},
    actions: {
        $push: '$action'
    }
}}])
```

This aggregate takes between **2h and 3h to finish**, but there's only ~ 3M documents in that day :

```
db.count({'created_at': { $gte:ISODate("2016-06-05"), $lt:ISODate("2016-06-06")}})
2,7 M
```

*(count lasted 5s to execute)*

The aggregate result is like the following:

```
{
    id_user: ObjectId(...),
    date: day_requested,
    actions:[action, action, ...]
}
```

The aggregate explain says that the query is using IXSCAN.

```
{
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "created_at" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2016-06-05T00:00:00Z"),
                        "$lt" : ISODate("2016-06-06T00:00:00Z")
                    }
                },
                "fields" : {
                    "action" : 1,
                    "id_user" : 1,
                    "_id" : 0
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "database1.collection1",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "created_at" : {
                                    "$lt" : ISODate("2016-06-06T00:00:00Z")
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "created_at" : {
                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2016-06-05T00:00:00Z")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "created_at" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "created_at",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "created_at" : [
                                    "(new Date(1465171200000), new Date(1465084800000)]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "id_user" : "$id_user"
                },
                "actions" : {
                    "$push" : "$action"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If I put a $limit pipe of 3M instead of the $match, the query last **1 minut instead of 3hours**. Is there anything wrong in the previous query?
How can I perform an aggregate of that size in a reasonable time?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your aggregation pipeline and the result you gave certainly do not match. Where are you aggregating the field `date` in your pipeline as implied by the result?

Comment: @chridam Yes, sorry about that, the output is an example of what it will be, at the moment I only have only `id_user` and `actions` on the aggregate $group (the same with the id_user, that is outside the _id on the output, it will have the $project with $dateToString and the correct formatting when it works)